# Install more if not all r-cran-* packages

Tags: r, streamlit, apt, cran, r2u

Currently trying to use streamlit for simple deployment. To install r packages I have a `packages.txt` file containing the packages e.g.

```
r-base
r-base-dev
r-base-data.table
r-cran-mlr3
```

When deploying the app this will run something like `apt-get install r-base` etc. However, I do get errors when they are not available:
`E: Unable to locate package r-cran-mlr3`

From what I understand only a small number of CRAN packages can be installed this way. Is there a way to add more if not all the CRAN packages so that `apt install r-cran-*` would work?

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [`r2u` project](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/), which provides

> *all CRAN packages* (modulo at best handful of blacklisted ones) including all packages needing compilation

This is way more than the [set of packages listed on the main Debian site](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=r-cran&searchon=names&suite=unstable) (which I got to from the [CRAN Debian page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/)).

The README linked above gives setup information.

(I have `r2u` set up on Pop!OS 22.04 [based on Ubuntu 22.04] and had no trouble with `apt-get install r-cran-mlr3`)

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks BenBolker!

Comment: I was guessing that you had mistakenly assumed that OP was *already* using `r2u` ...

Comment: To be candid, I do recognize the potential benefits of `r2u`, but occasionally (more often than I'd prefer) our clients' needs require newer versions of "something" than the CRAN versions support. Or we need a feature that was pushed to CRAN yesterday and hasn't migrated yet to `r2u`. Or I'm administering an instance of Posit Connect that _will not_ use `r2u`, needing instead to compile it for any/every version of R that our apps support. You know. *It's complicated* (usually said without full proficiency of the target system ... :-/).

Comment: This is great - if I understood it correctly, this would only work if I install it with root permissions or via the Docker container?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @r2evans Coming here late (first post on tag `r2u` and nobody told me !!) but please note that a) we are generally 'business day + 1' and b) a genuine gem is that you can combine `r2u` with binaries (for jammy !!) from `r-universe` which we sometimes do for CI and other things.  I wrote a helper `installRub.r` (for "install r-universe binary") for `littler` just for that and it is *great* to not spend those 20 minutes compiling packages such as `arrow`, or `duckdb`, or `mlpack`, ...